# Changing the name of the sub folder inside Django Template path

Tags: python, django, jinja2, python-3.7, wsgi

I am new to Django and I have a path to my HTML file as

./templates/registration/login.html and I want to change it to 
**./templates/index/login.html**

After renaming it to /templates/index/login.html, it is still picking up the old directory /templates/registration, could not find login.html screen and it throws an error.

Could someone tell me what changes we have to make in **settings.py** when we rename a folder name inside templates structure?

Answer (score 0):

In your settings.py, you can define the templates location, which applies the template function per app.

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ( 
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
)
```

I assume your app is named registration, hence why it is looking there. You can either rename your app or place all your templates in a global folder at the same level as the apps (and not within the apps themselves). The latter is not recommended for large applications.

Edit: Why is this labeled Python2? What version of Django is this?

Comment: It also seems that maybe you need to change the location in your `views.py` to point to the correct subfolder.

Comment: I just changed the version to python3.7. I will try this out and let you know